# Can I make my html page write to a word document using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, export, local

My father has asked me to make him a program that has places for him to write text, a drop down, and a few places to put pictures. This program will then export the above to a word document (basically it’s just a template to make writing word documents faster for the same task)

Rather than me learn how to use python GUI programming, I figured it might be easier to just make him a local .html file for him to open, fill out, and click submit for it to be exported as a word file. Is such a thing easy or possible with html and JavaScript? I know JavaScript sort of goes against writing to the users system

Comment: Maybe not by writing to the system, but by downloading the file to the system

Comment: I am not sure you can export to word, but you can in PDF.

Comment: Ohh a pdf may work. Since the template makes it easy to edit it won’t matter that he can’t edit the PDFs. I’ll look into that!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Docx.js - it was made to solve this issue

Comment: Oh awesome, I'll look into it! When I tried googling this before all that came up was "can I save my word doc as an HTML file" lol. I need the opposite of that. I'll mark your reply as the correct answer once I look into this and see if it'll work :)